# How to access RefImpl data inside js script

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, ref

I have js code to access data from firebase look like this:

```js
const { user } = getUser();
const { documents: mahasiswa } = getCollection("mahasiswa", ["userId", "==", user.value.uid]);
console.log(mahasiswa);
```

The output of the console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ3yD.png)

But, how i can access the data inside RefImpl inside of my js code, example:

```js
let angkatan = mahasiswa.angkatan
```